# URLSearchParams is not defined error when running tests with jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jasmine, jestjs

How can I use URLSearchParams when running tests with Jest ?

When I do so I get

`ReferenceError: URLSearchParams is not defined`

Answer (score 1):

You just need to upgrade your version of `react-scripts` which uses the newest version of Jest that contains the ability to use URLSearchParams.

You can read more about it here: https://facebook.github.io/jest/blog/2017/12/18/jest-22.html#good-bye-node-4-welcome-jsdom-11.

Comment: Ok, what is the oldest version that supports URLSearchParams, and how do we upgrade to it?

Comment: @MegaMatt Have you already found a solution? I'm running react-scripts 1.1.4 which seems to be the latest version, but I'm still getting this error.

Comment: react-scripts 1.14, which is the latest major release, still uses Jest 20. You can confirm this by looking at your package.json file inside the jest folder of your node_modules folder. Support for URLSearchParams was added in Jest 22. So the answer is: unless you want to manually change the version of Jest that react-scripts is using (which is not recommended), you simply won’t be able to use URLSearchParams in your tests. Pending an update of react-scripts that uses Jest 22+, I modified my tests to use the query-string npm package instead of URLSearchParams.

Answer (score -1):

Are you setting your jest environment to something other than the default in your config file?
You must run set the jest environment to be `jsdom` so that common browser specific JavaScript components are availible

```
jest --env=jsdom
```

See [Configuring Jest](http://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/configuration.html#testenvironment-string)

Comment: @Lev Could you update your answer with any config files if any and a sample of your failing test to help people troubleshoot your error